# magento showing wrong price

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Having a strange problem with magento price display. We have 10 user group and each user group has different pricing. On product detail page it shows correct price but on list view it shows default product price instead of group price of that logged in user. It get corrected if I do a re-index (all the index already showing ready though) but the next day it starts showing wrong price again and once I do a re-index it start showing correct price. Why this happening even if I am not changing price and all the indexes are showing ready.

How often we need to do re-indexing in magento and why its changing even if we are not doing any changes to product data and price.

Comment: is your cache enable or disable ?

Comment: No Vishal, my Cache is disabled

Answer (score -1):

Please use this code for Group  Price if any issue please let me know.

```
<?php  $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

 if($groupId ==""){?>

          <?php if($product->getSpecialPrice()){?>

         <?php echo "$".$rprice = number_format($product->getPrice(),2); ?> </div>

          <?php }else{?>

          <?php  $product->setCustomerGroupId($groupId); 

       echo "$".$price = number_format($product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice(1, $product),2); ?>

          <?php } ?>

        </div>

        <?php if($product->getSpecialPrice()){ echo "Special Price $".number_format($product->getSpecialPrice(),2);?>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php }else{echo "$".$price = number_format($product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice(1, $product),2); }

 ?>
```